# Copy and paste template rows to the row below the active cell

Tags: vba, excel, row, copy-paste

My goal is that I can select one of three row-templates, located in rows 1 to 3, and depending on where I am with the cursor the selection should be inserted a row below. This code works fine and inserts the selected template-row:

```
Sub InsertRowBelow()
RowNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(1).Row
SelectTemplate = InputBox("Which row level do you want to insert?                    1 = Title, 2 = Subtitle, 3 = Task")
Worksheets("Projektplan").Rows(SelectTemplate).EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("Projektplan").Rows(RowNumber).EntireRow.Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Projektplan").Rows(RowNumber).Paste
End Sub
```

but in the end it generates an error (*VBA error 438 object doesn't support this property or method*).

Why is that?

Comment: thanks alot, it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once [Application.CutCopyMode = False](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839532.aspx) has run there is nothing to Paste, so this line:

```
Worksheets("Projektplan").Rows(RowNumber).Paste
```

is returning the error. It is not required so may be removed.